# I sent a list of string to server with volley. How I can read this data in php and run query with them?

Tags: php, android, mysql, pdo, android-volley

I am completely newbie in programming and my English is not so good. I faced a problem on my project . 
I have the String ArrayList that it contains just some numbers as String . 
with follow code I convert it to Gson I think.

```java
String finalRequestedList = new Gson().toJson(listOfWordsId);///// is my string arraylist///
```

with volley I sent it to server . It has sent something like this to the server :

```java
["1080","16","17","18","2154","151","0","3","1762","6","127","7","91","70","72","20"]
```

I tried to receive this data with follow line

```php
$content = $_POST['wordsList'];
```

Now I want to know what should I do with $content  to run query like this  :

```php
$query="SELECT newG.dId,newG.dWord ,newE.word FROM newG  LEFT JOIN newE ON newG.dId = 
newE.id where newG.dId= 1080,16,17,18,...(all received numbers);
```

and the last part of my code is like this :

```php
$result=$connection->query($query);
$rows = array();
while ($assoc_row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $assoc_row;   
}
print json_encode($rows);
}catch(PDOExceptoin $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Comment: Does it help? https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in

Applied to your code it should look something like this:

```
$content = $_POST['wordsList'];

$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($content) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT newG.dId,newG.dWord ,newE.word 
    FROM newG  
    LEFT JOIN newE ON newG.dId = newE.id 
    WHERE newG.dId IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($content);
$rows = $stm->fetchAll();
print json_encode($rows);
```

There is no need for the loop, you can use `fetchAll()`.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response . I use this code but I don't know why it back 2 times of everything . like this :

{"dId":"6","0":"6","dWord":"die Tochter","1":"die Tochter","word":"daughter","2":"daughter"},{"dId":"7","0":"7","dWord":"jetzt","1":"jetzt","word":"now, currently,","2":"now, currently,"}

one time it show the colum name with value and one time it show the index with value , the second time is not required .what did I wrong ?
Could you help me on this case ?

Comment: Read [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). The first parameter is fetch style. Use constant `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` for example: `$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`